# filter records in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having a dummy dataframe like-

```
account    account_type
  1          A
  1          B
  1          C
  2          A
  2          A
  3          C 
  3          D
```

I want to filter only those account which have multiple account_type and it will return vector of all those account. So it will loop through the complete dataframe and gives vector of all account which are basically assigned to different account type(i mean account_type value is more than 1).

so the final output is - 1,3

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, .(nacc = uniqueN(account_type)), by = account][nacc > 1, toString(account)]
## [1] "1, 3"
```

Doing something similar in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(account) %>%
  summarise(nacc = n_distinct(account_type)) %>%
  filter(nacc > 1) %>%
  summarise(toString(account)) %>% 
  pull()
## [1] "1, 3"
```

Where:

```
df <- data.frame(
  account = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), 
  account_type = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "C", "D")
)
```

Comment: I made the slight modification in input dataframe. So account 2 although comes two times but still it is assigned to same account_type, so it will not be a part of output.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following. Remove duplicate entries. Subset the result of `table` and extract the `names`.

```
d <- d[!duplicated(d),]
names(table(d$account)[table(d$account)>1])

#[1] "1" "3"
```

**Your data**

```
d <- read.table(text="
account    account_type
  1          A
                1          B
                1          C
                2          A
                2          A
                3          C 
                3          D", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the `Plyr` library:

```
library(plyr)
test=count(df, c('account')) # Count the frequency based on account type
test[test$freq>1,1]   # Select the account with freq>1
```

Output:

```
[1] 1 3
```

**Another approach**

```
library(plyr)
test=ddply(df, .(account), nrow) # Calculate the occurence of account
test[test$V1>1,1]  # Select the account with occurence>1
```

Output:

```
[1] 1 3
```

Comment: @andy: I have added answer for you. Could you please check and let me know incase you need further details.

Comment: @andy:  Please consider to upvote or accept the answer if it was helpful to you. Also see: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution. We can use the `tapply` to apply the `table` function to count the type of each `account`, extract the table name, and keep the one with more than one name.

```
r_list <- lapply(tapply(dat$account_type, dat$account, FUN = table), names)
r_vec <- names(r_list[sapply(r_list, length) > 1])
r_vec
# [1] "1" "3"
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "account    account_type
  1          A
  1          B
  1          C
  2          A
  2          A
  3          C 
  3          D",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to filter records in R:

```
with(unique(dat), unique(account[duplicated(account)]))
# [1] 1 3
```